# Offset (смещение) для растра

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opencv

Для произвольной фигуры, представляющей из себя просто вектор с точками, имеется возможность производить смещение. Уменьшать, либо увеличивать без строгого соответствия начальной форме.

Для демонстрации привожу небольшой пример:

[image: полигон]

Исходное состояние - серый цвет, результат - зелёный. Впрочем, можно и наоборот, суть роли не играет.

На всякий случай хочу отметить, что это не масштабирование (scale), т.к. при использовании последнего зелёный полигон (точнее сказать, в примере их два, большой и маленький) был бы просто уменьшен с точным сохранением формы. Но нужно именно то, что показано на картинке. Причём для растровой маски.

Да, при помощи методов, имеющихся в OpenCV (да и даже если просто свой цикл реализовать), можно получить векторы пограничных пикселей маски, а затем использовать для смещения, но хотелось бы избежать лишней конвертации. То есть выполнить смещение сразу на растре.

Навскидку приходят в голову операции дилатации и эрозии, но у них имеется недостаток, заключающийся в том, что если брать большое ядро для выполнения морфологической операции, то получим усиленную "квадратизацию" модифицированного полигона. Иными словами ровненькие линии, такие как в примере не получатся. Если же брать маленький размер ядра, но взять больше итераций, то это работает достаточно медленно, причём чем больше дельта (разница между исходником и результатом), тем больше потребуется итераций и тем дольше будет выполняться алгоритм. Часто такая скорость совершенно неприемлема.

Каким ещё способом, кроме обозначенных морфологических операций возможно решить данную задачу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, вас может заинтересовать статья [CPU vs GPU. Distance field](http://habrahabr.ru/post/245729/) на Хабрахабре.

Там с помощью ядра

[image]

получают

[image]

Чем больше ядро, тем меньше угловатость и тем меньше скорость. Реализации на CPU и GPU прилагаются: [Distance Field Samples](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dfsamples/).

Comment: Это, похоже, то, что нужно с небольшой модификацией под мою задачу, т.к. мне нужно проще, чем то, что предоставляет этот алгоритм. Ещё там упоминается (не в самой статье, но по ссылкам) и Distanse Transform, который также может быть применён для решения моей задачи. В общем, очень полезно, спасибо.